# How should I identify the most important motivations to my respondents - factor means or variance explained by factors? (detected by EFA)

Tags: factor-analysis, survey, exploratory-data-analysis

I have 11 motivations (M1-M11) in my questionnaire for ocean swimming. After running an EFA, I detected 4 underlying latent factors (relaxation, socialization, etc.) which explained 62% of the variance.

Relaxation: M1,M2,M3 (17% variance explained, Factor mean=3.7)
Socialization: M4,M6 (16% variance explained, Factor mean=3.9)
Factor 3: M5,M7,M8 (15% variance explained, Factor mean = 3.0)
Factor 4:M9,M10,M11 (14% variance explained, Factor mean = 3.2)

Whereby factor mean is the average likert scores of motivations making up each factor (e.g. Factor mean for Relaxation is (sum of M1,M2,M3 scores)/no of respondents)

I want to know which motivations/groups of motivations are most important to my respondents. Should I then use variance explained by each factor, or the mean score of motivations making up each factor?
I.e. If I use variance explained, "relaxation" factor explains the most variance. But if I use factor mean, then it would be "socialization" factor.

Another question would be if I use variance explained, would it be right to say that all 4 factors are relatively equal in importance, or in driving the way my respondents answer these questions?

Thanks all!

Comment: 1) "Important" can be understood and formulated operationally in varied ways. So, it is difficult to answer. 2) 4 factors from 11 items in EFA - I would say, it is a bit too many factors extracted.